# how much caching in wordpress is too much

Tags: wordpress, caching

I'm working on a wordpress installation.  They are using four caching plug-ins, plus a fifth plug-in has multiple levels of caching:

```
Cloudflare CDN
Redis Object Cache
W3 Total Cache
OPTIMIZATION IO
Performance (with 6 kinds of caching).
```

I'm thinking this is a bit of an overkill.  I'm afraid of too many caching systems becoming counterproductive.  I know I need cloudflare CDN for image and loading speed, but I can't tell where one starts and one stops.  Can someone tell me where to go with this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your sites traffic, but I would say your fine with just the W3 total cache plugin or Cloudflare CDN services. What you have seems over kill and might even cause issues. Also using php 7 with op_cache well really help speed up your site if its slow.